# Is there a way i can use my refresh indicator to refresh a fututre builder after an error snapshot

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm fetching data from Newsapi.org, i need to be able to reload the futurebuilder() after a snapshot error, i'm very new to flutter so this might sound strange.

I've already been able to fetch my data, and also tried putting the call back into the
`if(snapshot.hasError) {}`
but i just cant't get it to work

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var refreshIndicator = RefreshIndicator(
        key: refreshKey,
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Source>>(
          future: list_sources,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(
                  'An error occured, check your internet connection and try again');
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data != null) {
                List<Source> sources = snapshot.data;
                return new ListView(
                    children: sources
                        .map((source) => GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            ArticleScreen(source: source)));
                              },
                              child: Card(
                                elevation: 1.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 14.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                                      width: 100.0,
                                      height: 140.0,
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                          "lib/images/newspaper 2.png"),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Row(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: Container(
                                                  margin:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          top: 20.0,
                                                          bottom: 10.0),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    '${source.name}',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 18.0,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight
                                                                .bold),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            child: Text(
                                              '${source.description}',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.bold,
                                                  color: Colors.grey),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            child: Text(
                                              '${source.category}',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.bold,
                                                  color: Colors.black),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList());
              }
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
        onRefresh: refreshListSource,
      );
```

I expected slididng from the top on the screen with the error to try to reload the data

Comment: what is the code in `refreshListSource` function. Plus it should be `onRefresh: refreshListSource(),` not `onRefresh: refreshListSource`,

Comment: `Future<Null> refreshListSource() async {
    refreshKey.currentState?.show(atTop: false);

    setState(() {
      list_sources = fetchNewsSource();
    });

    return null;
  }`

Comment: and i can't use refreshListSource(), _The argument type 'Future<Null>' can't be assigned to the parameter type '() → Future<void>'._

Comment: `onRefresh: () => refreshListSource(),`

Comment: If you call setState((){}) it will make a rebuild of the widget executing again de future of the FutureBuilder

Comment: @Sebastian I don't get that, can I use it in an inkwell to reload? `if (snapshot.hasError) {
return InkWell(
 onTap: () {
 setState(() {});
  },
 child: Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
 child: Text('An Error Occoured, click to try again.'),
),
);
}`

Answer (score 0):

@Sebastian put refreshKey outside the build method, the screen won't get back to top when it rebuilds.

```
  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
```